# Is it possible to do the transpilation with a priori retired devices?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

Is it possible to do the transpilation with "any" device in qiskit? I would be interested in doing this with already retired devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have two options.

**Option 1** - If the backend is part of `qiskit.providers.fake_provider` you can just load it and transpile for it:

```
from qiskit.providers.fake_provider import FakeLima
from qiskit import transpile
from qiskit.circuit.library import EfficientSU2

backend = FakeLima()

circuit = EfficientSU2(backend.configuration().num_qubits)
transpile(circuit, FakeLima()).draw('mpl')
```

[image: transpiled EfficientSU2]

or

**Option 2** - You can define a coupling map by hand. For example:

```python
from qiskit.transpiler import CouplingMap
coupling_map = CouplingMap([(0,1), (0,2), (2,1), (3,2), (2,3), (4,1)])
coupling_map.draw()
```

[image: coupling map graph]

And then transpile in for that custom-defined coupling map:

```
from qiskit import transpile
from qiskit.circuit.library import EfficientSU2

circuit = EfficientSU2(backend.configuration().num_qubits)
transpile(circuit, coupling_map=coupling_map).draw('mpl')
```

[image: result of transpiling in the previously defined coupling map]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Sorry for the late reply, but another tiny question if I may. I'm noticing that e.g. fakelima returns a little bit different circuit than the retired lima. Is there a way to match both transpilation procedures?